# Tabulator range slider to update filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator, nouislider

I am currently using a range slider and am stuck as I cannot easily clear/update the previous values filters. This is the code that takes in values from the slider and set the filters on the table.

```
function priceFilter(values){
    table.setFilter([
    {field:"price",type:">=", value: values[0]},
    {field:"price",type:"<=", value: values[1]},
    ]);
}

function gallonFilter(values){
    table.setFilter([
    {field:"gallons",type:">=", value: values[0]},
    {field:"gallons",type:"<=", value: values[1]},
    ]);
}
```

[Here is a JSfiddle of what I currently have](https://jsfiddle.net/dmahon1213/pa6ujwcs/3/) that does not work as intended. This is due to setFilter wiping all previous filters. So only one slider is working at a time.

[Here is one "solution" I have found](https://jsfiddle.net/dmahon1213/uv7jfd2w/1/) that does the correct behavior, but looks awkward as the table reloads twice on a slide (once starting, once ending). This works by removing the previous filter at the start of the slide, then adding new filters at the end.

How can I update the values in these filters that does not cause the table to reload, or at least make it not as visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***setFilter*** function is designed to replace all existing filters. If you simply want to add another filter to existing filters then you should us the ***addFilter*** function

```js
table.addFilter("age", ">", 22);
```

Full details on how to manipulate filters can be found in the [Filter Management Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/filter#manage)